# Replacing all words except one - regex perl

Tags: regex, perl, string

i try to have a regular expresion which will change `"dir1/dir2/"` to `"dir1/dir3/"`
only if `dir2` is not `tmp`, and if it is `tmp` ,I want it not to change and stay `"dir1/tmp"`.

I think I need a lookahead regex but I cant manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use if statement before applying the s////.... check using m// if tmp is not there and then replace.

Comment: Could be written even shorter (and more understandable) as `m/.../ or s/.../.../`

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead assertion to do the substitution only if there is not `tmp` after `/dir1`:

```
s#(dir1/)(?!tmp/)[^/]+#\1/dir3#;
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/oEQvM)

Answer (score 2):

```
s{^([^/]+)/(?!tmp/)[^/]+/}{$1/dir3/}
```